# How do I dynamically change where the X and Y axes start?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have a c3 line chart set up like this.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: "#chart",
    data: {
        url: dataFile,
        x: "year"
    }
});
```

`dataFile` is a CSV file that looks like this.

```
year, data1
1990, 10
1992, 20,
1993, 30
```

and so on...

Without changing the data source, how do I make the X axis start at 1992 (or any other year I choose), and the Y axis start at the `data1` value at 1992 -- in this case 20?

Comment: Are you going to exclude the row "1990, 10" from being shown then? (trying to understand and formulate my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the extent of the axes using the axis configuration --> https://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-max

However to update it according to the contents of the data is a bit more involved, but this does it -->

http://jsfiddle.net/jaw2rdes/3/

Specifically, in the oninit configuration function we can access the data and use it to set the axis mins we want

```
oninit: function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
      var xval = 1991;
      var matchSeries = 'data1';
      var index = (chart.x()[matchSeries].indexOf(xval));
      if (index >= 0) {
         var yval = chart.data.values(matchSeries)[index];
         chart.axis.min({
              x: xval,
              y: yval,
          });
        }
   }, 0);
}
```

However, bear in mind this
a) produces an animation at the start (though this can be turned off)
b) doesn't remove any data points, they're just hidden to the left/bottom of the axes displayed